# convert vb6 to autoit

Tags: vb6, autoit

can anyone help me convert this to autoit, or at least tell me how i can do this in autoit?

```
Private Const DC_PAPERNAMES = 16

Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
    Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesW" ( _
    ByVal lpDeviceName As Long, _
    ByVal lpPort As Long, _
    ByVal iIndex As Long, _
    ByVal lpOutput As Long, _
    ByVal lpDevMode As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim P As Printer

    For Each P In Printers
        lstPrinters.AddItem P.DeviceName
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub lstPrinters_Click()
    Dim P As Printer
    Dim lngPapers As Long
    Dim strPaperNames As String
    Dim lngPaper As Long
    Dim strPaperName As String
    Dim lngActualLength As Long

    Set P = Printers(lstPrinters.ListIndex)
    lngPapers = DeviceCapabilities(StrPtr(P.DeviceName), _
                                   StrPtr(P.Port), _
                                   DC_PAPERNAMES, _
                                   0, _
                                   0)
    strPaperNames = String$(lngPapers * 64, 0)
    lngPapers = DeviceCapabilities(StrPtr(P.DeviceName), _
                                   StrPtr(P.Port), _
                                   DC_PAPERNAMES, _
                                   StrPtr(strPaperNames), _
                                   0)
    lstPapers.Clear
    For lngPaper = 0 To lngPapers - 1
        strPaperName = Mid$(strPaperNames, 64 * lngPaper + 1, 64)
        lngActualLength = InStr(strPaperName, vbNullChar) - 1
        If lngActualLength > 1 Then strPaperName = Left$(strPaperName, lngActualLength)
        lstPapers.AddItem strPaperName
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thread where someone is trying to do the exact same thing: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/25857-need-a-help-from-the-pros-on-making-api-call/

There is also a guide which will help you write windows API calls: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/7072-dllcall/ it deals mainly with finding the correct type conversion which is the only hard part.